# Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument wholenump -47) when press 'enter' in orgorg

Tags: org-mode

Every time, I press 'Enter' in org docs
it prompts

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument wholenump -47)
  make-list(-47 nil)
  lisp-indent-initial-state()
  indent-sexp()
  paredit-newline()
  funcall-interactively(paredit-newline)
  call-interactively(paredit-newline nil nil)
  command-execute(paredit-newline)
```

google search returns few answer to the debugger error.

What's the problem?

Comment: Might it be that you have lisp or emacs-lisp code blocks in your org file? The lisp parser causes the problems in connection with paredit. If you switch paredit off the problem should be gone.

Comment: inform us about `emacs-version`, `org-version`, and the version of paredit. Can you reproduce the problem with `emacs -Q` after `M-x package-initialize` `<RET>`?

Comment: This might be [Bug#35286](https://debbugs.gnu.org/35286) or [Bug#30891](https://debbugs.gnu.org/35286)

Comment: org-version 9.1.9 emacs-version 26.1. cannot reproduce the problem with emacs -Q @Tobias

Comment: @npostavs I took the next step and proposed the OP to try your patched version.  Please post your own answer when the OP confirms that your patch fixes his problem. You can use the code I cited from your bugfix in your answer. Note, that I only used the minimal patch, not the additional function.

Comment: @npostav Hm. I actually answered on your behalf. I would like if you could take the credit for your pointer to [Bug#30891](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30891). I propose that you copy my answer from "There are two indicators" up to the end and post it as your answer. Afterwards I will delete mine so that only yours can be accepted and rewarded. Please give me some notice if you are done. Sorry for the trouble. (My actual reason for answering was that your patched code does not fit into a comment.)

Comment: @Tobias I don't really see the point in copying your answer; you've already credited me in the text, and my name is on the patches in the Emacs git repo. Digesting the bug report patch into an easy-to-use init file snippet is what you get credit for, which seems fine to me.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks for your statement. Then we leave everything as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npostavs referenced [Bug#35286](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=35286) and [Bug#30891](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30891) in [his comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51247/debugger-entered-lisp-error-wrong-type-argument-wholenump-47-when-press-en?noredirect=1#comment79016_51247).

Note: I do not want to take credit for Noam Postavky's findings. The hard task is to find the bug. I just "copied" his patch here. So, please try the proposed bugfix.

You told us that your `emacs-version` is 26.1. That leaves us only with [Bug#30891](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30891).

There are two indicators that your problem is [Bug#30891](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=30891):

- The problem deals with negative depths.
- The problem is found in Emacs 26.1 and fixed in Emacs 26.2.

This problem should be fixed with the following code in your init file:

```el
(defun lisp-indent-calc-next-patch (state)
  "Move to next line and return calculated indent for it.
STATE is updated by side effect, the first state should be
created by `lisp-indent-initial-state'.  This function may move
by more than one line to cross a string literal."
  (pcase-let* (((cl-struct lisp-indent-state
                           (stack indent-stack) ppss ppss-point)
                state)
               (indent-depth (car ppss)) ; Corresponding to indent-stack.
               (depth indent-depth))
    ;; Parse this line so we can learn the state to indent the
    ;; next line.
    (while (let ((last-sexp (nth 2 ppss)))
             (setq ppss (parse-partial-sexp
                         ppss-point (progn (end-of-line) (point))
                         nil nil ppss))
             ;; Preserve last sexp of state (position 2) for
             ;; `calculate-lisp-indent', if we're at the same depth.
             (if (and (not (nth 2 ppss)) (= depth (car ppss)))
                 (setf (nth 2 ppss) last-sexp)
               (setq last-sexp (nth 2 ppss)))
             (setq depth (car ppss))
             ;; Skip over newlines within strings.
             (nth 3 ppss))
      (let ((string-start (nth 8 ppss)))
        (setq ppss (parse-partial-sexp (point) (point-max)
                                       nil nil ppss 'syntax-table))
        (setf (nth 2 ppss) string-start) ; Finished a complete string.
        (setq depth (car ppss)))
      (setq ppss-point (point)))
    (setq ppss-point (point))
    (let* ((depth-delta (- depth indent-depth)))
      (cond ((< depth-delta 0)
             (setq indent-stack (nthcdr (- depth-delta) indent-stack)))
            ((> depth-delta 0)
             (setq indent-stack (nconc (make-list depth-delta nil)
                                       indent-stack)))))
    (prog1
        (let (indent)
          (cond ((= (forward-line 1) 1) nil)
                ;; Negative depth, probably some kind of syntax error.
                ((null indent-stack)
                 ;; Reset state.
                 (setq ppss (parse-partial-sexp (point) (point))))
                ((car indent-stack))
                ((integerp (setq indent (calculate-lisp-indent ppss)))
                 (setf (car indent-stack) indent))
                ((consp indent)       ; (COLUMN CONTAINING-SEXP-START)
                 (car indent))
                ;; This only happens if we're in a string.
                (t (error "This shouldn't happen"))))
      (setf (lisp-indent-state-stack state) indent-stack)
      (setf (lisp-indent-state-ppss-point state) ppss-point)
      (setf (lisp-indent-state-ppss state) ppss))))

(with-eval-after-load 'lisp-mode
  (if (version<= "26.2" emacs-version)
      (warn "If you exclusively use Emacs >= 26.2 you can remove `lisp-indent-calc-next-patch'")
    (advice-add 'lisp-indent-calc-next :override #'lisp-indent-calc-next-patch)))
```