# Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument wholenump -98)

Tags: debugging, paredit

I am working on Org 9.1.8 and emacs 26.1,

Every  time I invoke Enter, it prompts

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument wholenump -98)
  make-list(-98 nil)
  lisp-indent-initial-state()
  indent-sexp()
  paredit-newline()
  funcall-interactively(paredit-newline)
  call-interactively(paredit-newline nil nil)
  command-execute(paredit-newline)
```

What' s the problem?

Comment: The first arg to `make-list` cannot be a negative number. Do you see this behavior if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If you do see the problem then `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it from `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Why do you ask [your question again](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51247/2370) [if it has already an accepted answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51264/2370)???

Comment: I added the solution to init.el @Tobias and report the above error.